# DOC to PDF converter

Tags: php, linux, centos, pdf, поиск-программ

Подскажите какой-то удобный конвертер. Хорошо если это будет либа php-шная, но пойдет и какая-то даже программа (разумеется под линукс) которую можно вызвать командой (типа `convert src dest`). Надо чтоб работала с doc, docx, rtf.

Comment: Если найдете, напишите ответ. я когда-то искал, но нашел только онлайн сервисы с кучей ограничений и, в большинстве случаев, с ухудшением качества изображений. Тогда я решил проблему поставив рядом комп с виндами, читал директорию через самбу, запускал ворда и спечатывал через акробат. Но сейчас у меня сервак не под боком, а иногда тоже надо

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/306408/

Comment: @donRumata это все конечно круто, но поднимать для конвертации виндовс-сервак - не вариант. У меня нет задачи что-то писать в ворд из пхп. Ничего настолько сложного. Только конвертация.

Comment: Ну тогда `libreoffice-common` или типа того.

Comment: @donRumata либра не запускается. Я с ней полдня возился. Она то работает, то виснет намертво. Не знаю что это.

Comment: Попробуй на ubuntu с подключенным официальным ppa: https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa. Вдруг это проблема конкретно центоси?

Comment: @donRumata причем тут убунта если у меня сервак на centos? Меня не интересует как либра работает на убунте, мне надо чтобы оно работало именно на моем серваке.

Comment: Я увидел. Но я бы сначала просто выяснил - это косяк тех, кто собирает конкретные пакеты под конкретную ось или собака где-то в другом месте зарыта. У нас пакеты в между сетями терялись. Сервер был на дебиане. В ходе ковыряния выяснилось, что косяк конкретно в ядре конкретно дебиана. И в бубен он тоже мигрировал. Пересели на центось - всё поехало. Тебе советую провести такой же эксперемент. Воткнуть другую ось и посмотреть как там себя будет вести либра.

Comment: @donRumata куда воткнуть и зачем? У меня на домашнем ПК стоит убунта, либрой пользовался, хотя сейчас предпочитаю onlyoffice. Я знаю что она там работает, но что с того? Я не собираюсь переустанавливать ОС на серваке))))))

Comment: Ты так и не понял что я хочу донести. Ну ок.

Comment: Microsoft Office 365 / Microsoft Word (нет, я не шучу).

Comment: @0andriy метку линукс в теме что плохо видно?

Comment: Грубить не стоит

Comment: @0andriy Где вы увидели грубость? А вот минус теме вы явно необоснованно поставили, т.к. тема очень актуальна - в пхп как выясняется почти нет возможностей для работы с документами, а она часто бывает нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Можно с помощью стандартного для убунты Libre Office

```
lowriter --convert-to pdf filename.doc
```

Или ещё можно таким образом

```
sudo apt-get install abiword
abiword --to=pdf filename.doc
```

Comment: Сервак на CentOS. Не знаешь как туда поставить эти штуки? Там yum. Просто не знаю названия пакетов. Есть ли они там вообще? И что лучше lowriter или abiword?

Comment: @DarkByte в принципе любой офисный пакет может конвертировать, но abiword не смог найти для cent OS, так что вот мануал по установке Libre, попробуйте https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/install-libreoffice-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Comment: В любом случае это костыль, устанавливать офис ради конвертера, но насколько знаю, отдельно конвертера нет. По крайней мере не встречал

Comment: Это не костыль, это пакет с функционалом. Для операций со специфическими типами файлов задействуется пакет для его понимания, операций с ними. То же что и .NET в более широком смысле для запуска .NET приложений. Удобнее использовать пакет нежели чем делать самописный код для поддержки многочисленных версий и совместимостей.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov это понятно, но можно было бы извратиться и вытянуть конкретный функционал из пакета, благо в Linux подобное можно делать, однако немного лень, да и смысла не имеет)